# Locally $p-$integrable function on an open set that satisfies additional condition must be $0$ almost everywhere on the open set?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, lebesgue-integral, alternative-proof

Suppose that $f$ is a Lebesgue measurable function defined on an arbitrary open set $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$. Furthermore, assume that $f \in L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}(\Omega)$ and that

$$ \sup_{x \in \Omega, \, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^p \, dy < \infty, $$

where $\lambda$ is an arbitrary real constant such that $\lambda > n$.

**GOAL.** My goal is to show that, under these conditions, it follows that $f = 0$ almost everywhere on $\Omega$.

**Precedent work and why it fails.** Severin Schraven has provived an answer to this problem that we thought to be good enough. After some time, while re-analysing this question, I figured out that there was a slight problem with his answer. The main result that he used was the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem which is usually formulated as

**Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem (LDT).** Given a function $g \in L^1_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb R^n),$ we have that

$$ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} g(y) \, dy = g(x) $$

for almost every $x \in \mathbb R^n$.

Schraven's answer was based on applying the LDT to $|f|^p \chi_\Omega$ but the problem is that with this version of the LDT we're unable to do this: note that $f \in L^p_{\operatorname{loc}}(\Omega)$ isn't enough to guarantee that $|f|^p \chi_\Omega \in L^1_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$. Therefore, I am looking for alternative aproaches to guarantee the desired result.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really should be a comment, but it’s a little too long for it.

With your assumptions, let $M_{\lambda}$ denote that finite supremum. Now, fix any point $x\in\Omega$. Since $\Omega$ is open, there exists an $r_x>0$ such that $B(x,r_x)\subset\Omega$. Then, for any $0<r<r_x$, we have that $B(x,r)\cap \Omega= B(x,r)$. Letting $c_n$ denote the volume of the unit ball, we have
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)|^p\,dy&=\frac{1}{c_nr^n}\int_{B(x,r)\cap \Omega}|f(y)|^p\,dy\leq\frac{1}{c_nr^n}\cdot M_{\lambda}r^{\lambda}=\frac{M_{\lambda}}{c_n}r^{\lambda-n}.
\end{align}
Since $\lambda>n$, we have that the LHS vanishes as $r\to 0^+$. Hence, by Lebesgue’s differentiation theorem, it follows that $f=0$ a.e on $\Omega$.

Notice I didn’t use the full strength of all your assumptions. In particular we can allow the $\lambda$ to depend on $x$, and we only need the $\limsup\limits_{r\to 0^+}$ to be finite for a.e $x\in \Omega$ (as opposed to the supremum over all $x$).

---

You’re right that if we’re in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$, it doesn’t necessarily imply we’re in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Bbb{R}^n)$, but it doesn’t matter because we’re considering integrals over smaller and smaller neighborhoods of a given point, so we can modify the function away from there.

> **Lebesgue’s Differentiation Theorem (on open sets).**
>
> Let $\Omega\subset\Bbb{R}^n$ be open, and fix a particular measurable function $f:\Omega\to\Bbb{C}$ which is in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\Omega)$. Then, a.e $x\in\Omega$ is a *Lebesgue point* of $f$, i.e satisfies
> \begin{align}
> \lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)-f(x)|\,dy&=0.
> \end{align}

Again, note that for all sufficiently small $r>0$, the sets $B(x,r)$ are contained in $\Omega$, so the integrals make sense. Also notice that I am referring to a specific function $f$ (not an equivalence class), because otherwise we cannot define the notion of *Lebesgue point* (since it uses the evaluation $f(x)$).

Let’s say you’ve already proved this theorem when $\Omega=\Bbb{R}^n$ and for $L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$ functions. To deduce the theorem in the above case, we simply localize the argument: we can find a sequence $\{U_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ of open sets such that each $\overline{U_n}$ is compact, and contained in $U_{n+1}$ and $\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}U_n=\Omega$. For each $n$, let us define $f_n:\Bbb{R}^n\to\Bbb{C}$ to be $f$ on $U_n$ and $0$ elsewhere. Then, $f_n\in L^1(\Bbb{R}^n)$, so for a.e $\xi\in\Bbb{R}^n$, we have
\begin{align}
\lim_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{|B(\xi,r)|}\int_{B(\xi,r)}|f_n(y)-f_n(\xi)|\,dy&=0.
\end{align}
In particular this equality holds for a.e $x\in U_n$, i.e there is a null set $Z_n\subset U_n$ such that for all $x\in U_n\setminus Z_n$, the above equality holds. But notice that since $x\in U_n$ and $U_n$ is open, for small enough $r>0$, we’ll have $B(x,r)\subset U_n$ and so the integrand above will become $f$ instead of $f_n$. In other words
\begin{align}
\lim\limits_{r\to 0^+}\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}|f(y)-f(x)|\,dy&=0.\qquad\text{($x\in U_n\setminus Z_n$)}
\end{align}
Since this is true for all $n$, we can upgrade the the above equality and deduce it holds for all $x\in \bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}(U_n\setminus Z_n)=\Omega\setminus\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}Z_n\right)$, which is $\Omega$ minus a countable union of measure-zero sets (which is still measure zero). Thus, we have shown that a.e point of $\Omega$ is a Lebesgue-point of $f$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I found it really helpfull. I wasn't aware of this version of the LDT for open sets, and I believe that was the main issue. I still have a question I would like to make: at one point in the answer you state "Since $\Omega$ is open, there exists an $r_x > 0$ s.t. $ K:= \overline{B(x,r_x)} \subset \Omega$".  You seem to never use this $K$ again in the rest of the answer. Is there any particular reason why you used the closure of a ball? I.e., if we stated "Since $\Omega$ is open, there exists an $r_x > 0$ s.t. $B(x,r_x) \subset \Omega$" wouldn't we obtain the same thing?

Comment: @xyz you’re right I never use it again (so you can ignore that). Initially I wrote the second part of the answer while interweaved into the first but then decided to separate the arguments.

Comment: I think everything is fine now (except for the small typo where you wrote LHS instead of RHS). I have only one further question: do you have any book reference for the LDT on open sets?

Comment: @xyz not a typo. Sure, the RHS does vanish, but the important thing is that by the squeeze theorem, the LHS vanishes. And no I don’t have any references; it seems like a simple enough corollary.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that $\Omega\cap \partial \Omega\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is a null set (this covers in particular the case when $\Omega$ is open). By abuse of notion I will denote by $f$ the extension of $f$ by zero to all of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

We have for $x$ in the interior of $\Omega$

$$ \lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} r^{-n} \int_{B(x,r)\cap \Omega} \vert f(y) \vert^p dy = \lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} r^{-n} \int_{B(x,r)} \vert f(y) \vert^p dy = c_n \vert f(x)\vert^p $$

for almost every $x$ in the interior of $\Omega$ by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem (here $c_n$ is the Lebesgue measure of the unit ball). Hence, for $\lambda>n$ we get

$$ \lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)\cap \Omega} \vert f(y)\vert^p dy =\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} r^{-(\lambda-n)} r^{-n} \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} \vert f(y)\vert^p dy= \infty$$

for almost every $x\in \Omega$ (as $\partial \Omega$ is a null set by assumption) sucht that $f(x)\neq 0$. Thus, $f\in L^{p,\lambda}(\Omega)$ implies that $f$ vanishes almost everywhere as
$$\lim_{r\rightarrow 0^+} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)\cap \Omega} \vert f(y)\vert^p dy \leq \sup_{r>0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r)\cap \Omega} \vert f(y)\vert^p dy.$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe that I understood your reasoning, but there is one detail that is confusing me: during your reasoning you've considered the integral over $B(x,r)$, which is the default procedure given by the LDT. In the definition of the Morrey spaces I provided, the integral is over $B(x,r) \cap \Omega.$ How can your answer be adapted to take this small detail into account?

Comment: @xyz It makes no difference. We can just use an indicator function. See my edit.

Comment: Thanks. I believe that I understood it. Just to confirm the last step: after concluding that $$ \lim_{r \to 0^+} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^p \, dy = \infty $$ we use the fact that $$ \lim_{r \to 0^+} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^p \, dy \leqslant \sup_{x \in \Omega, r > 0} r^{-\lambda} \int_{B(x,r) \cap \Omega} |f(y)|^p \, dy ? $$

Comment: @xyz Yes, this is how we conclude.

Comment: Dear Severin, today I have unmarked your answer as accepted because, while re-analysing this question, I have some questions about the answer you provided. Firstly, I am having trouble guaranteeing that the Lebesgue Differentiation Theorem is applicable here. The version of LDT I am familiar with is the following: Let $f \in L^1_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$. Then $$ \lim_{r \to 0} \frac{1}{|B(x,r)|} \int_{B(x,r)} |f(y)| \, dy = f(x) $$ for almost every $x \in \mathbb R^n$. The point is that I am not sure we can guarantee that $|f|^p \chi_\Omega \in L^1_{\operatorname{loc}}(\mathbb R^n)$.

Comment: Check this post for context: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4872723/g-in-lp-operatornameloc-omega-longleftrightarrow-gp-chi-omega

Comment: Can you be more detailed on why it works for open sets $\Omega$ ? I have seen your edit in the answer but couldn't understand it

Comment: @xyz If $x$ is in the interior of $\Omega$ then there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\subset\Omega$ and hence $B(x,r)\cap \Omega=B(x,r)$ for those $r$. I am not sure what else could be unclear.

Comment: @xyz Or what is unclear to you? I am just saying in the interior I can use the standard Lebesgue differentiation theorem (as sufficiently small balls or contained in $\Omega$) and we don't care about the boundary if it is a null set. My argument does not work general open sets (as the boundary of an open set can have positive measure), however, I do not state that in my answer.

Comment: I see. Do you think it's possible to adapt the argument somehow to make it work for arbitrary open sets $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^n$ ?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven seems like OP just added the hypothesis that $\Omega$ is open? So, Lebesgue’s differentiation fully answers the question in the affirmative (regardless of what the boundary of $\Omega$ does) that $f=0$ a.e on $\Omega$.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Indeed, I am not sure what I was thinking... thanks!